# Ansible run task list as a standalone playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a task list `do_smth.yml` that I am including in a playbook `main.yml`. I can run `ansible-playbook -i inventory main.yml`, but is there a way to also run `do_smth.yml` directly from the command line? Something like `ansible-playbook -i inventory --hosts all --tasks do_smth.yml`.

I don't want to modify `do_smth.yml` to add `hosts:` and `tasks:` because I also want to include it as a task list in `main.yml`.

=== EDIT 1: Adding more context ===

```yaml
# do_smth1.yml #
- name: Do something 1
  shell: echo "1" > ~/.config/my.cnf

# do_smth2.yml #
- name: Do something 2
  shell: echo "2" > ~/.config/my.cnf

# main.yml #
- hosts: all
  vars:
    users:
      - me
      - someone_else
      - stillsomeone
  tasks:
    - name: Execute action 1 for each user
      include_tasks: do_smth1.yml
      loop: "{{ users }}"
    - name: Execute action 2 for each user
      include_tasks: do_smth2.yml
      loop: "{{ users }}"
```

Now, I would like to be able at some point to execute only `do_smth1.yml` for a specific user, without modifying `main.yml`. Something like `ansible-playbook -i inventory --hosts all -e '{"users": ["customusr1","customusr2"]} do_smth1.yml`

Comment: `ansible-playbook` runs playbooks, not task lists. My feeling is that you should have a look at [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) and [collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections.html) but it's hard to tell without further details.

Comment: I'm interested. Modified the question and added more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick solution, use tags. In `your_playbook.yml`

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    users:
      - me
      - someone_else
      - stillsomeone
  tasks:
    - name: Execute action 1 for each user
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks:
        file: do_smth1.yml
        apply:
          tags:
            - do_smth1
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      tags:
        - do_smth1
      
    - name: Execute action 2 for each user
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks:
        file: do_smth2.yml
        apply:
          tags:
            - do_smth2
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      tags:
        - do_smth2
```

Then either call:

```
# Play all tasks
ansible-playbook -i my_inventory my_playbook.yml
# Play only smth1 tasks
ansible-playbook -i my_inventory -t do_smth1 my_playbook.yml
# Play only smth2 tasks
ansible-playbook -i my_inventory -t do_smth2 my_playbook.yml
```